# Problema ao utilizar Route::resource em servidor de produção

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Estou fazendo um sistema utilizando o **Laravel 5.6**

Subi para um servidor que tenho e acesso este externamente

Porém estou tendo problemas quando a rota utiliza o resouce, por exemplo:

```
Route::resource('materiais', 'MaterialController');
```

As rotas que criei normais usando `Route::get`, `Route::post`, `Route::patch`, etc.., funcionam corretamente

Por exemplo se estou em

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/novaordem`

e vou para abrir uma nova ordem ele segue para o endereço

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/ordemservico/2/create?`

funcionando corretamente, a rota esta assim:

`Route::get('ordemservico/{id}/create', 'OrdemServicoController@create');`

porém se estou em

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/materiais`

e vou em cadastrar novo material a url fica assim:

`http://192.168.0.23/materiais/create`

A função de chamada está assim:

```
public function create()
{
    $unidades = Unidade::all();
    return view('materiais.create', compact('unidades'));
}
```

E o da ordem de serviço assim:

```
public function create($id)
{
    if($id == 0){
        $setores_internos = SetorInterno::all();
        //$setores = Setor::where('setor_id', 5)->get();
        $meios = Meio::all();
        $bairros = Bairro::all();
        $servicos = CadastroServico::where('setor_id', 5)->get();
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

        return view('ordemservicos.create',compact('data','id','setores_internos','meios',$
    }else{

        $cidadao = Cidadao::find($id);
        $meios = Meio::all();
        $servicos = CadastroServico::whereNotIn('setor_id', [5])->get();
        $enderecos = Endereco::where('cidadao_id', $id)->get();
        $setores = Setor::whereNotIn('id', [5])->get();
        $horas_servico = ConvertTime::convertToTime($cidadao->horas_servico);
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

        return view('ordemservicos.create',compact('cidadao','meios','servicos','setores',$
    }
}
```

e pela falta do `sisobras/public/` da um erro de `Not Found`

Quando uso o sistema com o `php artisan serve` rodando na mesma máquina funciona tudo corretamente

Comment: As rotas criadas qnd vc usa o resource são também nomeadas, vc está usando o nome delas no link que vc clica para ir pro `/materiais/create` ? Caso não saiba o nome, vc pode usar o artisan `php artisan route:list` e verificar o nome da rota e então no seu link, colocar `{{ route('nomeDaRota') }}`

Comment: @morkhusz o encaminhamento é feito pelo controller não no link. A questão não é essa, pois como disse ali a rota criada normalmente funciona, se criar as próprias rotas do resource só que "abertas" ele funciona corretamente. Porém com o resource ele retira o /sisobras/public